# Android App shouldn't reset to Feed after pressing Home

Tags: feature-request, android-app

As of Android App v1.0.41, if I leave the app by pressing home, then upon returning to it, I'm reset back to the Feed. In previous versions, I would just be able to return to exactly where I was before: viewing the same question, writing the same answer, etc.

Leaving the app by some other means - using Recent Apps, for instance - *doesn't* reset the app back to the Feed. It's just via pressing home.

The app *shouldn't* reset me to the feed when I press home. I should just be returned to where I was. Home isn't an exit button. Please change it back to the way it was before.

*Not* resetting is how most Android apps work. There are some official apps that do reset back to the start (Messages, Phone, Settings), but those have good reason to behave that way and it's not destructive for them to do so. In the Android App, it can be a pain to dig my way back to the question or answer I was reading (if I even remember how to find it), or I might altogether lose a question I was writing because I don't expect it to trash the question and return me to Feed when I press home.

(In case it's just me: I'm on a HTC One with Android 4.4.2)

Comment: How are you returning back to the app? By selecting it from the app list? By tapping it on one of your home screens? What launcher are you using?

Comment: HTC Sense launcher (the stock launcher for the HTC One). I keep the Stack Exchange app in a folder on my home screen. I experience the same behaviour when it's outside of a folder, or launched from the app list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't happen on my end. It may be happening because your phone is low on RAM and killing the app when it goes to the background, or it may be happening due to issues we've noticed before with some launchers. The stock launcher on a Nexus 4, for instance, went back to the feed each time you tapped on the icon from a home screen, but the Google Experience launcher on a Nexus 5 didn't.

Since this is happening to you *everywhere*, not just in home screens, I'm assuming it's something to do with low RAM. Does it also happen if you restart your phone?

Anyone else that experiences this: Please leave a comment with your phone and OS, thanks!

Comment: I've just restarted my phone, and it doesn't do this now - your instincts were spot on. That makes a lot of sense, because I didn't remember it doing this yesterday...

Comment: Even with the iOS app if you quit by swiping it out of the app switcher and launch again it launches into the Feed. It would be nice if it *always* remembered where you were

Comment: @mhlester Isn't swiping it out of the launcher on iOS conventionally supposed to make an app forget everything and return to the start? (If the launcher is the word for the area that recalls your recent apps - it sounds like that's what you're describing)

Comment: @Jonathan it forces the app to close entirely, yes, but many apps still launch back to where they left off, even if you restart the phone